# Parsing JSON data of improper naming convention in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing, java-8

I have JSON data, which is improper in terms of *naming convention* but modifying the data source is not something in my hand :

```
{
  "Type": "Trains",
  "globalPoint": "c84e5f61-648d-4074-b2b1-b144ea8ee876",
  "Id": "7b0c72bb-236a-49f5-9b70-4b74ed3a6096",
  "StartIds": {
    "0": [
      4103,
      4156
    ],
    "2": [
      2645
    ],
    "3": [
      1904
    ]
  },
  "Topic": "CityOneToCityTwo"
}
```

If you see the `StartIds` in above json, it has terms like `0` / `2` etc which i can't define as variable name. This is my parser class with line in issue as mentioned

```
Class Data{  
  String type;
  String globalPoint;
  String Id;
  List<Points> startIds;        // This is where the problem lies
  String topic;
}
```

Points.java

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Points {
    private int n;
}
```

Initially i thought of making `List<Points> startIds;` to `Object startIds;` but it still fails.

Any suggestion on how i can parse this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"StartIds":` could be represented as `Map` of `String` and `List<Points>`

```
Map<String,List<Points>> startIds;
```

instead of

```
List<Points> startIds;
```